# I am getting CLS poor value

Tags: core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift

I am getting CLS issues and i dont know why

If you watch this picture you will can see i have reserved space to all elements that after are loaded

Then, why CLS is poor?

How is this possible?

Help me please

[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL you're testing?

Comment: Yep, would be helpful to know the URL to help you @mdromed